# Tabify Your SharePoint Forms: list to tabs (need to add more to jquery script)

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, web-parts, editview

I am using a very helpful script provided by Mark Rackley found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSmuailCvKI (I made some minor adjustments but the script is found here http://www.markrackley.net/2015/12/03/tabify-your-sharepoint-forms/).  The script works great but I am trying to add code that will allow me to choose specific fields I want in specific tabs.  For example, right now if I create 'Tab 1' with 'Size 5' that first tab will automatically choose the first 5 fields from my list of available fields.

In my current project, mt first tab is 'Finance' related. This means I only need fields 1, 5, 16, 20, and 25 from my list of fields. Field 2-4 are not related to finance so I would not need them in the first tab.

I am wondering if this is possible or if the only option is to edit my list in the order I need them to be in and just use the current script.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.markrackley.net/scripts/jquery.HillbillyTabify.min.js?rev=1"></script> 

<div id="HillbillyTabifyDiv"><ul id="HillbillyTabify"></ul></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        //the example below creates 3 tabs, you can create as many tabs as you'd like by adding additional objects.
        //"Title" is the title of the tab and "size" is the number of fields to show in that tab
        //If there are any remaining fields they will appear as normal below the tabs
        var tabInfo = [
            {title:"Title 1",size:3},
            {title:"Title 2",size:4},
            {title:"Title 3",size:5}
        ];

        HillbillyTabifyForms(tabInfo);

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the default edit/new/display forms, you should just reorder your fields in the list itself.

if you're creating custom edit/new/display forms you should go into SharePoint Designer, and reorder the fields in the edit form, new form, display form that you have for your list.

when you're done reordering, it'll pick up the fields that you want per tab

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was able to find html code that basically linked the code in my initial post (to create the tabbed headers) and then a custom view list.  As you mentioned, I just had to plug in the fields from the list that I wanted into each of the tabs.  Thanks again!